# Is it possible to get scaled size of UIControl?

Tags: objective-c, uikit

I'm trying to make custom control (like UIButton) manually which can recognize user's touch.

So, when even **custom control's superlayer is scaled**, I want to know if user's touch point is contained in custom control's frame.

thus I need to know scaled size of custom control.

Is CALayer support this property or function?

Sorry. Previous code has faults so I have edited the code like following.

```
uiView1 = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)] autorelease];
uiView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
uiView1.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(uiView1.transform, 2.0, 2.0);

scaledButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
scaledButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 40);
[scaledButton setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

nonscaledButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
nonscaledButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 40);
[nonscaledButton setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[uiView1 addSubview:scaledButton];
[self.view addSubview:uiView1];

[self.view addSubview:nonscaledButton];


NSLog(@"uiButton1 width : %f, height : %f", scaledButton.frame.size.width, scaledButton.frame.size.height);
NSLog(@"uiButton1 width : %f, height : %f", scaledButton.layer.bounds.size.width, scaledButton.layer.bounds.size.height);

NSLog(@"uiButton1 width : %f, height : %f", scaledButton.realFrame(???).size.width, scaledButton.realFrame(???).size.height);
```

Can't know how to get scaled size... => scaledButton (200,80)

following is running result.

/Users/nice7285/Library/Caches/appCode10/DerivedData/RealSize-e4f66643/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealSize.app/RealSize
Simulator session started with process 1567

2012-09-01 16:52:31.124 RealSize[1567:15d03] uiButton1 width : 100.000000, height : 40.000000

2012-09-01 16:52:31.126 RealSize[1567:15d03] uiButton1 width : 100.000000, height : 40.000000

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get CGRect after like CGAffineTransformScale like this:

```
 CGAffineTransform newtransform = CGAffineTransformScale([scaledButton transform], 2.0, 2.0);

 CGRect newFame = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(scaledButton.frame, newtransform);
```

Comment: I think that this answer will be hint.